# how do you inner join a table that has 1 value per row to another table that has 2 values per a row separated by a comma in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, string, inner-join

So, say you are working with a field **rowid** in the table **rcheck** under database **fildb**, which is a primary key. So here is the field **rowid**, with the records 9800000...9800003:

**rowid**

9800000

9800001

9800002

9800003

I want to do inner join to the field **rfile_rowids** from the table **rfile** under database **fildb**, which has 2 values in each record separated by comma because I am trying to match records. Here is **rfile_rowids** with the 2 values separated by commas:

**rfile_rowids**

0,9800000

0,9800001

0,9810000

0,9820000

So far, I did:

**SELECT**

**rc.rowid,rf.rfile_rowids**

**FROM fildb.rcheck rc**

**INNER JOIN fildb.rfile rf**

**ON rc.rowid LIKE SUBSTRING(rf.rfile_rowids,1,9);**

However, my program keeps running and won't stop running, and I have to stop executing it. So my question is how do you inner join a table that has 1 value per row to another table that has 2 values per a row separated by a comma in MySQL?

Comment: have you tried  without like clause?  For ex INNER JOIN fildb.rfile rf ON  
 rc.rowid = SUBSTRING(rf.rfile_rowids,3,9) . How ever, calculating substring for each row itself is a heavy operation but time will depend on the number of rows.

Comment: Are you trying to join on the second number after the comma?

Comment: yes, and also want to understand the exact problem. So, there can be many solutions. Again it depends on number of rows.

Comment: Well if you are trying to join on the second number you should try changing your join code to "rc.rowid = SUBSTRING(rf.rfile_rowids,3,9)"

Comment: @AlexSapozhnikov, yes I want to match the numbers in the field rowid to the second numbers after the comma in the field rfile_rowids

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do INNER JOIN fildb.rfile rf ON rc.rowid = SUBSTRING(rf.rfile_rowids,3,9), and see if I get any matching records

Comment: No joins will be able to use indexes and therefore will be slow.